# does $y^3=(z^2-1)/(z^2+1)$ conflicts with the fact that genus $2$ riemann surface can not be embeded in $\Bbb{C}P^2$?

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm learning some basic content about Riemann Surface with Farkas&Kra's *Riemann Surface*. In Section III.10.3 I saw The **Corollary 2**(Outline of the proof can be found in [How to prove that a Compact Riemann Surface is a projective algebraic curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320386/) too):

> a. Every non-hyperelliptic surface of genus 3 is a submanifold of $\Bbb{C}P^2$
>
> b. Every other surface of genus $g \geq 2$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb{C}P^3$.

And from [Is there a complex surface into which every Riemann surface embeds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488512/is-there-a-complex-surface-into-which-every-riemann-surface-embeds) I know that  no Riemann surface of genus 2 can be embedded in $\Bbb{C}P^2$.

Hence it means every Riemann surface of genus 2 cannot be wrote as $F(z, w) = 0$ for some polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[z, w]$, or equivalently it cannot be wrote as $F(Z, W, X) = 0$ for some homogenous polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[Z, W, X].$ It has to be some algebraic curve of the form $\{(z, w, u)| f(z,w, u)=0, g(z, w,u)=0\}$, or equivalently $\{[Z, W, U, X]| F(Z, W, U, X)=0, G(Z, W, U, X)=0\}$.

But I saw a construction for a genus 2 Riemann Surface in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401141/:

$$
y^3=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}
$$

Hence it means $\{[Z, Y, X]|(Z^2+X^2)Y^3=X^3(Z^2-X^2)\}$ is a genus 2 Riemann Surface in $\Bbb{C}P^2$. Since it's the zero set of a homogeneous polynomial of three complex variables, it can be holomophicly embeded into $\Bbb{C}P^2$(is this argument correct?), which seems to be a confliction with the fact that genus 2 Riemann surface cannot be embeded in $\Bbb{C}P^2$.

Did I understand something wrong? Originally I thought all compact Riemann surface can be wrote as $f(z, w)=0$ but then the corollary tells me it's no the case. And then I found this example, it seems to be a contradiction and makes me confused.

Edit: Setting $X=0$ in $(Z^2+X^2)Y^3=X^3(Z^2-X^2)$, I got $Z^2Y^3 = 0$, which seems to contain some singularities in the infinity line. Is that for this reason the curve does not contradict with the fact that no Riemann surface of genus 2 can be embbed in $\Bbb{C}P^2$?

And in Farkas&Kra's Book section 0.3, I saw

> Examples of compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ are the surfaces of the algebraic functions:
> $$
>  w^2 = \prod_{j=1}^{2g+2}(z-e_j), e_j \neq e_k \text{ for } j\neq k
> $$

For $g > 1$ it has some singularities in the infinity line so it doesn't contradict the fact genus 2 Riemann surface cannot be embeded in $\Bbb{C}P^2$ too? Is this right?

Thanks!

Comment: Nowhere did the OP in the linked question say that it can be embedded in CP^2.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Does writting a Riemann Surface as a zero set of a polynomial of two variables mean that it can be embedded in $\Bbb{C}P^2$? I thought it’s the way

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thanks. You are right. The algebraic equations I posted doesn't mean it‘s an embedding. In Griffiths‘s *Introduction to algebraic curve*， I found a basic fact(Theorem 2.2) that solves my confusion too.

Comment: It says that any plane algebraic curve can be normalized to a compact Riemann surface and any compact Riemann surface $\tilde{C}$ can be through the normalization of a certain plane algebraic curve $C$ at most ordinary double points.